# Angular2 decorate code not copy to the js depend on the class order?

Tags: angular

I found out depend on the order I put my class at TypeScript, the javascript won't generate the angular __decorate functions, bug for TypeScript right? or am I doing it wrong?

1. **Error** on console, platform-browser.umd.js:2306EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on AppComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{name.firstname}} man!</h2>
    <h3>{{name.id}}</h3>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="name.firstname" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
export class Name {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
}
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'hi yo';
    name: Name = {
        id: 1,
        firstname: 'tt'
    };
}
```

2. This is working...

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export class Name {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{name.firstname}} man!</h2>
    <h3>{{name.id}}</h3>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="name.firstname" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'hi yo';
    name: Name = {
        id: 1,
        firstname: 'tt'
    };
}
```

3. **Error** This is also break, same error.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export class Name {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
}
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'hi yo';
    name: Name = {
        id: 1,
        firstname: 'tt'
    };
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{name.firstname}} man!</h2>
    <h3>{{name.id}}</h3>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="name.firstname" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the decorators tell Angular, that the following class is a `Component`, `Directive` or `Pipe`. Of course, if you put the decorator elsewhere and Angular is trying to bootstrap your `AppComponent`, it doesn't know what class type it is.

So yes, your second example works, because you have the `Component` decorator on your `AppComponent` class, just as Angular expects it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you should now is that `@Component` decorator (or any other in fact too) is being attached to the **next class** it meets. So if you do:

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'hi yo';
    name: Name = {
        id: 1,
        firstname: 'tt'
    };
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{name.firstname}} man!</h2>
    <h3>{{name.id}}</h3>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="name.firstname" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
```

you can see the order of decorator <-> class is not valid. Just swap these two:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{name.firstname}} man!</h2>
    <h3>{{name.id}}</h3>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="name.firstname" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'hi yo';
    name: Name = {
        id: 1,
        firstname: 'tt'
    };
}
```

And remember:

#### Component decorator must be attached to the following class

Comment: make sense, if that's angular decorators' behavior, I guess we have to follow.